# How to find the matching environment command in tex mode?

Tags: latex

A latex environment looks like this:

```
\begin{envName}
body
\end{envName}
```

Is there a command to jump back-and-forth between matching `\begin` and `\end` commands? (One cannot simply use a regex search because environments can be nested)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LaTeX-find-matching-begin` and `LaTeX-find-matching-end` functions do this.

```
   AUCTeX offers keyboard shortcuts for moving point to the beginning
and to the end of the current environment.
 -- Command: LaTeX-find-matching-begin
     ('C-M-a') Move point to the '\begin' of the current environment.
 -- Command: LaTeX-find-matching-end
     ('C-M-e') Move point to the '\end' of the current environment.
```

Comment: It should be noted that `C-M-a` and `C-M-e` are bound to `beginning-of-defun` and `end-of-defun` resp. in *most* modes and they are available in every mode, not just LaTeX-mode. They are supposed to do the "right" thing in each case: e.g. `C-M-a` moves to the beginning of the environment in LaTeX-mode, the beginning of a function in C mode, the beginning of a defun (doh!) in emacs-lisp-mode and so on.